# set the url automatically opened in browser with webpack-dev-server in webpack2

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Can I custom the url that be automatically opened in browser? I found there is no api for that? Since that there is not a index under the project root, but the default url is localhost:8080. Or in the condition that I want to debug the page being developing.

Comment: If you need to change the host, set the `host` property. More here - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhost

Answer (score 7):

**September 2021 (webpack 5)**

From the documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveropen

In the dev server config

```
{
  ...,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  open: ['http://locahost:3001']
  ...
}
```

(and remove the `--open` flag from the `webpack serve` command

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of June, 2022.

Comment: Thanks removing the --open flag was key issue for me. I had --open flag on npm start command which seems to override the config file.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure you webpack.config.js like this:

```
 entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
 output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),,
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/static/dist/"
  },
  devServer: {
    publicPath: '/static/dist/',
    open: true, 
    openPage: 'static/dist/somefile.html' 
  },...
```

The important thing here is devServer.open and devServer.openPage. You have to enable devServer.open and set your custom url in devServer.openPage to open first in your devServer. My configuration in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
"build": "webpack --mode production",
"dev": "webpack --mode development"
},...
```

Finally run it by:

```
npm run start
```

Hope it helps. Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this plugin: 
[Open Browser Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/baldore/open-browser-webpack-plugin)

Follow this steps...

1. First of all install the plugin:

   `npm install open-browser-webpack-plugin --save-dev`
2. Remove the `--open` option from **package.json** or the `open: true` option from **webpack.config.js**, **devServer** configuration
   or the `open: true` in your webpack.config.js
3. Now you need to require and configure the plugin into webpack.config.js

   ```
   var OpenBrowserPlugin = require('open-browser-webpack-plugin');`

   module.exports = {
     ...
     ...
     ...
     plugins: [
       new OpenBrowserPlugin({ url: 'http://localhost:3000/mycustompath' })
     ]
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

devServer: {
open: true,
openPage: 'oa' /* when browser open this */
}

Answer (score 0):

**To open a specified page in a browser:**

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    open: ['/my-page'],
  },
};
```

Usage via the CLI:

```js
npx webpack serve --open /my-page
```

You can find this section https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/